# Edit text field in extjs

Tags: java, jsp, extjs, extjs3

I have a text field which is populated by ExtJS DateField and the format for that should be "m/d/y G:i" which is then passed to Java and then to a stored procedure that will fetch data from the table according to date & time specified.

```
Ext.each(textFields, function(textField) {
    var dateField = new Ext.form.DateField({
        allowBlank:false,
        format:'m/d/Y G:i',
        style: {
            height: '22px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana',
            fontSize: '10px',
            float: 'left',
            marginTop: "1px"
        },
        applyTo: textField
    });
    dateFields.push(dateField)    
});
```

How to hide the time format displayed in text field, but the current system time should be passed to Java.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by hide the time format in the text field, can you elaborate a little more on that?

Comment: If I give format as "m/d/Y G:i" in the text field its shows date followed by time , I don't want time to be displayed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is both a `format` and a `submitFormat` config int the `Ext.form.DateField` class

Comment: Even if i give `submitFormat` its not serving my purpose

Comment: you set format to "m/d/y" and submitFormat to "m/d/y G:i" ?